# casting a soap object to a own object

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2

Can I cast a SoapObject to a predefined java object?. I use ksoap2
I am trying to do it inside an AsncTask class and this is my code segment.
I have created a class called `Citizen`.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
citizen = (Citizen)result;
```

the error I get is `cannot cast SoapObject to Citizen`

I have my AsynType Declaration like this.

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, Citizen>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What library provides `SoapObject`?

Answer (score 0):

No experience with this but when I read the javadoc of SoapObject it looks like your Citizen class must implement the `KvmSerializable`interface so you can:

```
KvmSerializable result = (KvmSerializable)envelope.getResponse();
citizen = (Citizen)result;
```

or why not directly:

```
citizen = (Citizen) envelope.getResponse();
```